# Analysis Sup proof

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am a physics student and am self teaching analysis so from time to time would like to get clarification on how accurate my proofs are (no matter how basic they are).

Question: Let $S$ be a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$
.Prove inf$S$ $\leq$ sup$S$.

$Proof:$ Since $S$ is bounded there exists an $s_0$=sup$S$ $\hspace{0.1cm}$ such that $\hspace{0.1cm}$ s$\leq$$s_0$$\hspace{0.1cm}$ and an $\hspace{0.1cm}$ $a_0$=inf$S$ $\hspace{0.1cm}$  such that $a_0 \leq$s $\hspace{0.1cm}$ $\forall s \in S$. Thus $a_0 \leq s \leq s_0$ $\implies$ $a_0 \leq s_0$ $\implies$ inf$S$ $\leq$ sup$S$  []

If people could point out whether I have missed anything obvious or assumed something incorrectly it would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks ok to me, but I think you might have a typo? You wrote $\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$, did you mean $\forall s \in S$?

Comment: This is fine. I would write the proof as follows: *Since $S$ is non-empty, there exists $s \in S$. Then $\inf S \leq s \leq \sup S$, from which we can conclude that $\inf S \leq \sup S$.*

Comment: @AlanChung Ur right I did mean that.

Comment: @azif00 This. It's important to say we take a specific $s$. Because as it appears in the OP, one might wonder why do we even need $S$ to be nonempty.

Comment: @azif00: you also need to state "Since $S$ is bounded both $\inf S$ and $\sup S$ are well-defined".